# Logic Building regarding new problems I have never gone through

Tags: java, loops, logic

I face problems when i get new problems , it might be lack of practice. I am beginner almost so I have just learn few patterns and basics of java. I got a problem of building a pattern but i wasn't able to build the exact logic of that. Actually, I know loops and all I am able to understand what is written there in program and what does it mean but when it comes to me to solve the problem with my logic building I am unable to that even after thinking hours and hours I wasn't able to find the solution. Please tell me how to overcome with this.

i have already explained that in my question itself

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), then update your question with a specific example, which includes some problematic code.